# Can an Arduino open and play video files off a Raspberry Pi with serial communication?

Tags: serial, communication

I just want to know if it is even possible to have serial communication from an Arduino Mega to Raspberry Pi 3, to open and play a specific video file stored on the Pi?

Comment: your question should really be `how to play video on an arduino?` ... it is irrelevant where the video is stored until you know if the arduino is capable of playing a video

Comment: Can arduino open and play video files from a computer with serial communication?  -The Pi is a computer.

Comment: serial bandwidth is sufficient to carry simple animations that arduino displays handle.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino does not have a video output device, so it will be tricky to get it to play a movie at all.

There are a number of add on displays for Arduinos, but most of these use a serial connection, and likely neither the connection nor the display itself has bandwidth to play a video.

If you were to hypothetically "play a video" on a serial display connected to an Arduino, you could do it just by copying the serial data from an external data source to the serial screen.  Exactly how this would work would depend on the screen's controller.  Most serial screens are at best capable of simple animations that would not quite qualify as "video".

However, I'm not sure what the point of this question is, since a Raspberry Pi does have a video output device (with HDMI or composite output depending on model) and can play videos by itself.  An Arduino isn't needed for this, and can't really help much.